# Find the product of $\log_{2005}(1/2)\log_{2004}(1/3)\log_{2003}(1/4)\cdots\log_2(1/2005)$. The bases are $2005,2004,2003,\ldots,2$

Tags: logarithms

This question was answered in this site itself by Mark Bennet. But I didn't understand how the logs got cancelled out.

Comment: Maybe you could add a link to the answer and be a little more specific on what your problems is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use formula:
$$\log_m n \cdot \log_n m=1$$
For example:
$$\log_{2005}\frac12\cdot\log_{2}\frac1{2005}=-1\cdot(-1)\log_{2005}2\cdot\log_{2}2005=1$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\log_{2005}(1/2)=\dfrac{\log(1/2)}{\log2005}=-\dfrac{\log2}{\log2005}$$

See [Change of Base of Logarithm](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laws_of_Logarithms#Change_of_Base_of_Logarithm)  and [Logarithms of Powers](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laws_of_Logarithms#Logarithms_of_Powers)